# PYTHON: How to delete a file in python after X amount of time, without constantly looking up the time

Tags: python, file, delete-file, auto-delete

I was making a temporary file storage website, and all of the features of it are completed, but due to it being a "temporary" file storage website, it needs to delete files and make space for more files, but how'd one go about making a system that automatically deletes the file after let's say 1 hour of time or `x` minutes of time?

The file is stored in the database has the following properties:

1. `HASHED_FILE_NAME` - The hashed file name of the original file, the way it is stored in the directory, let's say the file is called `test.mp4` so what the program will do is that, it will run a hashing algorithm using python's `secret.token_hex()` method, which will ultimately convert it to a string like `bf290fa34cf185ae.mp4`.
2. `LINK_TO_THE_FILE` - It is basically to add a extra layer of authentication so that no stranger stumbles upon the file on it's self, so it uses the same hashing function as before (`secrets.token_hex()`), but it is used to point back to the `HASHED_FILE_NAME` so let's say if you go to the link `MY-WEBSITE.com/files/04f579669576dbe4` the code `04f579669576dbe4` is going to point back to `bf290fa34cf185ae.mp4` which was originally `test.mp4`.
3. `PRIMARY_KEY` - This is pretty self explanatory, it just stores the primary key for the file.
4. `DATE_CREATED` - This might be useful, it stores the date the file was uploaded on the server.

I just can't figure out how to use these properties of the file to delete the file after `x` amount of time, without constantly looking up the current time in the program.

Any solutions or suggestions are gladly accepted!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: The easy way is to use `cron`.  Set up a `cron` job to call your clean up code once an hour.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts! I will definitely make sure to check that out

Comment: so metadata about the file is in Database and actual file on the local system?

Comment: Yes that's how it is setup @niko